# Using a Dictionary with PredicateBuilder?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, resharper, predicatebuilder

I have a `Dictionary<string,object>` of `search terms and values`. In this case the `term` is the `key`.  An example is:

```
var args = new Dictionary<string,object>() {{"name","joe"},
                                            {"occupation","salesman"}};
```

I am using the `PredicateBuilder` to build the `Where` clause and it works, but I was wondering if there was a more concise way to do it with the `Dictionary` instead of having to call `if(args.ContainsKey(...)` for every `search term` in the `Dictionary`?  This is how I am doing it now:

```
List<Person> persons;
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Person>();

if (args.ContainsKey("name"))
{
    string name = args["name"].ToString();
    predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.name == name);
}


if (args.ContainsKey("name"))
{
    string age = args["age"].ToString();
    predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.age == age);
}

persons = _context.Persons.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Also, if I declare `string name` outside the `if block`, `resharper` says `Access to modified closure`, but does it matter in this case?  For example

```
string name;

if (args.ContainsKey("name"))
{
    name = args["name"].ToString();
    predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.name == name); //Access to modified closure
}
```

But in the above, I am not modifying `name` anywhere, so why does it tell me this?

I am new to PredicateBuilder, so if someone an explain what `PredicateBuilder.False<Person>()` means as opposed to `PredicateBuilder.True<Person>()` and what does the `Compile` method do?

Comment: What is `PredicateBuilder`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx.  I am assuming it is from the creator of LINQPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, if I declare string name outside the if block, resharper says Access to modified closure, but does it matter in this case?

The code will still work *despite* the fact that your code generates this warning.  This happens to not be a problem unless you modify the `name` variable some time before you actually invoke that closure.  In the code you've shown you never use it again, so it wouldn't be a problem, but if you ever modified it in code shown after the code you have it would be a problem.

Why do you want to do this in the first place?  For starters, I don't really see the point of the variable to begin with.  Why not just write: `x => x.name == args["name"]`?  If you *did* want a local variable for this, why would you want to scope it at the higher level?  You should always scope any variable at the lowest scope possible while still allowing it to be accessed where it needs to be.  You shouldn't be modifying it outside the `if`, so don't expose it outside the `if`.

> I am new to PredicateBuilder, so if someone an explain what PredicateBuilder.False() means as opposed to PredicateBuilder.True()

It creates an expression that resolves to `false` if invoked instead of `true`...

Note that `false || variable` is equivalent to just `variable`.  The reason you want to initialize it to false is to avoid special-casing the first actual check you want by initializing the `PredicateBuilder` there.  It allows each of your variables to be consistent and always `OR` whatever it is that the predicatebuilder currently resolves to.

> what does the Compile method do?

It compiles the expression into a delegate that can be invoked.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this, but you lost me on this `...he reason you want to initialize it to false is to avoid special-casing the first actual check you want by initializing the PredicateBuilder there...`  When would I want to use `.True<Person>()`

Comment: I agree with your local variables, I probably will just remove them. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Xaisoft Note that `true AND variable` is the same as `variable`.  You'd use `true` if you were and-ing the values, just as one example.  Obviously PB can be used for not just those two, but also even more complex operations involving some combination of both.

Comment: Anyway to make it more concise instead of having to check if the dictionary contains the key and if it does, then add it to the predicate?

Comment: @Xaisoft Not good ones; since you're accessing a different property for each value you'd need to use reflection to handle that in some sort of loop; that'd likely result in messier and harder to work with code than what you have.  I'd only resort to that if there were several dozen properties, and if you had that it's a sign something's wrong with your object.

Comment: OK. Thanks again.  Hope this question was worded better :)